# Nested for loop - Javascript FreeCodeAcademy question

Tags: javascript, for-loop

learning javascript through code academy and had trouble with question "Basic JavaScript: Profile Lookup'. I have found a simpler solution to mine on the internet that makes sense, but I would like to know why my code below doesn't work so I can learn from my mistakes. thanks.

Question:
We have an array of objects representing different people in our contacts lists. A lookUpProfile function that takes name and a property (prop) as arguments has been pre-written for you. The function should check if name is an actual contact's firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact. If both are true, then return the "value" of that property. If name does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact". If prop does not correspond to any valid properties of a contact found to match name then return "No such property".

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName == name) {
        for (var j = 0; j < contacts[i].length; j++) {
            if (contacts[i][j] === prop) {
                return contacts[i][j];
            } else {
                return "No such property";
            }
        }
    } else {
        return "No such contact";
        }
    }

lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

Comment: `return` terminates the function

Comment: Sorry could you explain further? Why shouldn't the function terminate at the locations I have? Isn't returning the answer the function is looking for? So there is no need for the function to continue after that

Comment: (try to use debugger ;) ) - else branch testing name has always `return`, there should be check if it is the very last index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment was posted with a partial answer

> return terminates the function

and you asked

> Sorry could you explain further? Why shouldn't the function terminate at the locations I have? Isn't returning the answer the function is looking for? So there is no need for the function to continue after that

Your code loops over *all* the contacts, and intends to find the match. If on the very first contact a match is *not* found it exits the function without ever being able to try the rest of the contacts.

---

There are also a few other problems with your code. The spec says:

> The function should check if name is an actual contact's firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact. If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.

You check the first bit correctly, but then the second you're checking the *value* of the property and not the name of the property:

```
for (var j = 0; j < contacts[i].length; j++) {
    if (contacts[i][j] === prop) {
```

You should instead loop over `Object.keys(contacts[i])`.

```
var keys = Object.keys(contacts[i])
for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    if (keys[j] === prop) {
```

In actual fact the whole thing can be written in just a few lines.

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
    var contact = contacts.find(x => x.firstName == name);
    if(contact == null)
      return "No such contact";
    var prop = Object.keys(contact).find(x => x == prop);
    if(prop == null)
      return "No such property";
    return contact[prop];
}
```

live example below

```js
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
    var contact = contacts.find(x => x.firstName == name);
    if(contact == null)
      return "No such contact";
    var prop = Object.keys(contact).find(x => x == prop);
    if(prop == null)
      return "No such property";
    return contact[prop];
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "foo"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "bar"));
```

Comment: Yeah thanks I was able to fix my answer  and understand where I went wrong with your corrections

Answer (score -1):

You dont loop through object property using index.
In the second loop

```
   {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    }
```

object cant be accessed via index so it has to be accessed via property name.

Anyway this is simplified answer

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
  contact = contacts.find(item => item.firstName == name)
  return contact[prop]
}

result = lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes")
console.log(result)
```